# Finding out difference records from two tables

Tags: sql

I have 250 records in one table and after extraction into stagging the count is 249 Records, 
I am missing one record.

how to find out the missing records in SQL SERVER ???

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from BiggerTable
where BiggerTable.id not in (select id from SmallerTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    *
from tableAll
left join TableLess
    on tableAll.ID = TableLess.Id
where
    TableLess.Id is null
```